# Determine all entire functions which are injective

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Determine all entire functions which are injective. This is it.

Now, I know all entire functions that are injective take a specific form under certain conditions, but the formulation seems a bit weird for me. I would appreciate if someone could help what the author's idea is with this.

Comment: What form do you think they take?

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:  I just looked up the definition of entire and found it requires holomorphic.  I was thinking any permutation of the base set, which is not specified here, would work.  I agree it is a duplicate.